Cannot see the HDRI image in material preview or render
I don't know what I did but I cannot see the HDRI image in my project.
This dont happens in a new project, only in my current project.
I've put world opacity to 1 and blur to 0.
But I cannot see the HDRI, only some colors changing if I rotate the view, like if I was using HDRI with blur to 1.
In render mode the same happens.
In material preview I'm using a blender HDRI image, in render viewport an image in nodes as environment image.
You can see in the image below, in the left a new project, in the right my current project.
How can I solve it?
Thanks in advance.


On the right side the cube looks like you are in orthographic view. Orthographic view is basically as if the camera has an infinite focal length, so the background is infinitely zoomed in and shows a single pixel filling the whole screen. If you are moving the view around, the background color should therefore change according to the color of the changing pixels.

You are right ! newbie issue hehe

@Richal To be fair, this explanation is not really obvious for most people I guess - or at least not the first thing that comes to mind.
